# ReactJS How to use Router's props inside app.js file

Tags: reactjs, react-router-v4

The app.js file of my project is following. For all other components I used `this.props.history.push('/')` to redirect to the specific path and it works as those components receives the `props`. But in this app.js I have tried to console the props values inside `constructor`, `componentWillMount` and `render` but all gives null array. Is there any way to use `this.props.history.push('/')` inside app.js ?

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {};
    console.log(this.props)
  }

  componentWillMount(){ 
    console.log(this.props)
    this.props.history.push('/')
  }

  render() {
    console.log(this.props)
    return (
        <Router>
            <div className="App">
                <Route exact path='/' render={(props) => <Login {...props} />} />
                <Route exact path='/dashboard' render={(props) => <Dashboard {...props}/>}/>
            </div>
        </Router>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Please upload a screenshot of what you get on the console.

Comment: What is the version of React Router you are using, in V4 history.push would not work.

Comment: @alowsarwar I use version 3.2.0

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use `withRouter`

```
import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom'

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {};
    console.log(this.props)
  }

  componentWillMount(){ 
    console.log(this.props)
    this.props.history.push('/')
  }

  render() {
    console.log(this.props)
    return (
        <Router>
            <div className="App">
                <Route exact path='/' render={(props) => <Login {...props} />} />
                <Route exact path='/dashboard' render={(props) => <Dashboard {...props}/>}/>
            </div>
        </Router>
    );
  }
}

export default withRouter(App);
```

that will give you access to the history object and allow you to push to new routes.  (I tested and verified before posting, so I know this works).

import it on the top of the file, then wrap `App` with it in the `export default`

Comment: I'm getting an error `You should not use <Route> or withRouter() outside a <Router>`

Comment: in your index.js file, did you `import { BrowserRouter as Router } from 'react-router-dom';` and then wrap your App inside of Router?  `<Router><App /></Router>`

Comment: awesome, glad to hear.  When using react-router, you should use that <Router> to wrap the App in index.js.  the only think Im aware of that would take priority over <Router> would be <Provider> if your using Redux. In that case in the index file it would be <Provider><Router> then <App>.

Comment: please upvote and approve the answer.  Im trying to get more rep so I can help out more people.